# navigate through defined values in cell with arrow key

Tags: excel, vba

I've programmed before but I'm new to [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) so please help me.

I want to have a user select a cell (any cell in a column) in a worksheet and then he/she should be able to press the "UP" or "DOWN" arrow keys to navigate through values.

It is similar to a drop down menu.

1. For example I would have predefined values such "STOP","GO","START".
2. When the user selects the cell and hit the up arrow key once, the value of the cell changes to "GO", hit the arrow key again, the value changes to "STOP", and so on ....

thank you any help!

Comment: Does it have to be up/down arrows? You can make a data selection box by using data verification rules (add a list with the choices you want). That way they can click on the cell and a list of choices will appear for them to select from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part 1

1. Right click your sheet tab
2. View Code
3. Copy and paste in the code below

This code tells Excel to run your arrow up and down macros only on **this** sheet. The code is deactivated when you leave the sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "UpOne"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "DownOne"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{UP}"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}"
End Sub
```

Part 2

1. Press ALt & F11 together to go to the Visual Basic Editor
2. Insert Module
3. Copy and paste the code below
4. Press ALt & F11 to go back to excel

   ```
     Sub UpOne()
           Select Case ActiveCell.Value
           Case ""
               ActiveCell.Value = "Ready"
           Case "Ready"
               ActiveCell.Value = "Set"
           Case "Set"
               ActiveCell.Value = "Go"
           End Select
       End Sub


    Sub DownOne()
       Select Case ActiveCell.Value
       Case ""
           ActiveCell.Value = "Go"
       Case "Go"
           ActiveCell.Value = "Set"
       Case "Set"
           ActiveCell.Value = "Ready"
       End Select
   End Sub
   ```

Your code will now cycle from

blank (if empty) - 1) ready - 2) set - 3) go  (for Up Arrow)

blank (if empty) - 1) go - 2) set - 3) ready (for DownArrow)

Comment: thanks brett! Thats exactly what I wanted! The only piece of code I needed to add was to click on the cell first before cycling through the values.

Comment: this is what I added ' Private Sub Worksheet_AfterLeftClick()
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "UpOne"
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "DownOne"
End Sub '

Comment: how would I make this only valid for cells in column J for example. I want this because I want the user to have different options listed depending on which cell in which column he/she selects?